# Problemas para almacenar datos en variable entera en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo el código de un programa para identificar si un número es par o impar. Utilizo el operador % para ayudarme con la operación. El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 

{
long int a;
cout << "determinar si es par o impar\n";


cin >>a;
if(a%2==0)
{
    cout << a <<" es par";
}
else 
{
    cout << a << " es impar.";
}


return 0;
}
```

En la consola al final puedo almacenar hasta cerca de 10 cifras y el programa funciona correctamente. Pero al momento de introducir más números (a pesar de haber declarado la variable como "long int") ocurre  que el valor de la variable que me muestran es diferente al que introduje. Aquí va el resultado obtenido en consola tras ingresar más de 10 números:

```
determinar si es par o impar

12345678910111213
2147483647 es impar.

--------------------------------
Process exited after 8.98 seconds with return value 0
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Comment: Porque el número máximo que acepta `long int` es 2147483647

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Y cómo podría almacenar números más grandes?

Comment: La tarea que quieres realizar es trivial. Puedes usar cadenas en lugar de números.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas `long long`, podrás almacenar hasta diecinueve cifras (9.223.372.036.854.775.807).

Pero si en realidad quieres ver si el número es par o impar y para eso sólo necesitas la última cifra, pues lee una cadena, asegúrate de que es un número y comprueba la última cifra:

```
string numero;
cout << "determinar si es par o impar\n";

cin >> numero;
if (std::all_of(numero.begin(), numero.end(), [](char c) { return std::isdigit(c) != 0; }))
{
    if ((numero.back() - '0') % 2)
        cout << "Es impar\n";
    else
        cout << "Es par\n";
}
else
    cout << "Eso no es un numero\n";
```

He probado con un número de más de cien cifras y funciona, puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/dTsIwFL5en@KIMWyJkKZrsxWQO59CjaldGY1bt6zdhSE8@zwFFDRZd3rO99Pv6L5f6Ea5eprurdPNWBnY2M6Hwah2S64znFhX305UU3eDDfs/NK3DV2@2hFgXoFXWpRmQA0lGj2pwqjW@V9qAD9WakOTsCm5szdCtSaK7McBmA7PKBDO01qkBvAXjocdbB7bF@upmUautg@32qrU7SNF2tVJN897t0jOw/DB1TPF4IS6Nq2L38pbqPXrqDA4wmDAODk5q6ytb25AicPcEdA3HLCMJrnB64NdV6U9cbQFzOs/gARhykmv8Z38TNUlM481//Bc9kh/8Bu7AdXHt0V1yX5a@JKVrcpwmTgUrJM15WQhZFozTXJaiYDgRRckkZTkiVCKBYc05kgTDvuRYURgrlZHFJXqVRS45/qXAg6bszIw@XMSPMlmie8kEzwU20ZiLiDJBvgE)</kbd>.